# What are the pros and cons of the common activation functions?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, comparison, activation-functions

I have heard that sigmoid activation functions should not be used on neural networks with many hidden layers as the gradients tend to vanish in deep networks.

When should each of the common activation functions be used, and why?

- ReLu
- Sigmoid
- Softmax
- Leaky ReLu
- TanH

Comment: See also this related question: [Comprehensive list of activation functions in neural networks with pros/cons](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/115258/82135).